# Lottery game in javascript

Tags: javascript

The user should enter five numbers and then after clicking the button another five numbers should be extracted randomly. Based on how many of the numbers guessed match with the random numbers, the program should print six different sentences.
 The problem is that I'm stuck, I don't know to to fix it

```html
 <!doctype html>
    <html lang=it>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>SUPERENALOTTO</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       
        function reset()
        {
            document.getElementById("numero1")"
            document.getElementById("numero2")"
            document.getElementById("numero3")"
            document.getElementById("numero4")"
            document.getElementById("numero5")"
 
        }
       
        function guessnumbers()
        {
       
            var num1,num2,num3,num4,num5,ran1,ran2,ran3,ran4,ran5,N,monete,listanum,ris1,ris2,ris3,ris4,ris5,tot,vincita;
           
            num1=document.getElementById("num1").value;
            num2=document.getElementById("num2").value;
            num3=document.getElementById("num3").value;
            num4=document.getElementById("num4").value;
            num5=document.getElementById("num5").value;
 
 
            monete=document.getElementById("monete").value;
 
            ran1=Math.floor((Math.random()*50));
            ran2=Math.floor((Math.random()*49));
            ran3=Math.floor((Math.random()*48));
            ran4=Math.floor((Math.random()*47));
            ran5=Math.floor((Math.random()*46));
 
            N=50;
             
           
         
            listanum.apply(null, {length: N}).map(Number.call, Number)
           
           
            if ((listanum[ran1]==num1)||(listanum[ran2]==num1)||(listanum[ran3]==num1)||(lista[ran4]==num1)||(lista[ran5]==num1))
            {
                ris1=1;
               
            }
            else ris1=0;
 
            if ((listanum[ran1]==num2)||(listanum[ran2]==num2)||(listanum[ran3]==num2)||(lista[ran4]==num2)||(lista[ran5]==num2))
            {
                ris2=1;
               
            }
            else ris2=0;
 
            if ((listanum[ran1]==num3)||(listanum[ran2]==num3)||(listanum[ran3]==num3)||(lista[ran4]==num3)||(lista[ran5]==num3))
            {
                ris3=1;
               
            }
            else ris3=0;
 
            if ((listanum[ran1]==num4)||(listanum[ran2]==num4)||(listanum[ran3]==num4)||(lista[ran4]==num4)||(lista[ran5]==num4))
            {
                ris4=1;
               
            }
            else ris4=0;
 
            if ((listanum[ran1]==num5)||(listanum[ran2]==num5)||(listanum[ran3]==num5)||(lista[ran4]==num5)||(lista[ran5]==num5))
            {
                ris5=1;
               
            }
            else ris5=0;
           
             
            tot= ris1+ris2+ris3+ris4+ris5
 
            if (tot==5)
            {
                vincita=(monete*20);
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=" CINQUINA:  Congratulazioni! Vinci "+vincita;                
            }
           
            if (tot==4)
            {
                vincita=(monete*10);
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=" Quaterna:  Congratulazioni! Vinci "+vincita;                
            }
 
            if (tot==3)
            {
                vincita=(monete*5);
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=" Terna:  Congratulazioni! Vinci "+vincita;                
            }
       
            if (tot==2)
            {
                vincita=(monete*2);
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=" Ambo:  Vinci "+vincita;                
            }
 
            if (tot==1)
            {
                vincita=(monete*1);
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=" Un solo numero indovinato: Non perdi e non guadagni ";                
            }
 
            if (tot==0)
            {
                vincita=(monete*0);
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=" Mi dispiace:  perdi tutto";                
            }
 
        }
       
 
   
    </script>
   
 
    </head>
 
    <body>
    <div id="titolo">
    <h1 id="myDIV">superenalotto</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="informazione">
    </div>
 
 
    <div id="gioco">
    <form>
        <p style="text-align:center; font-size:30px ">
       
 
 
 
 
        <br>
       
        1°Numero   <input type="text" id="num1" name="num1">
        <br><br>
        2°Numero   <input type="text" id="num2" name="num2">
        <br><br>
        3°Numero   <input type="text" id="num3" name="num3">
        <br><br>
        4°Numero   <input type="text" id="num4" name="num4">
        <br><br>
        5°Numero   <input type="text" id="num5" name="num5">
        <br><br>
 
        Numero pescato1  <input type="text" id="num6" name="num6">
        <br><br>
        Numero pescato2  <input type="text" id="num7" name="num7">
        <br><br>
        Numero pescato3  <input type="text" id="num8" name="num8">
        <br><br>
        Numero pescato4  <input type="text" id="num9" name="num9">
        <br><br>
        Numero pescato5 <input type="text" id="num10" name="num10">
        <br><br>
 
        <h2 style="font-size: 30px; "> Inserisci la tua scommessa</h2>
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="monete" name="monete">
        <br><br>
        <input type="button" id="submit" name="Gioca" value="Gioca" onclick="guessnumbers()">
        <br><br>
       
        <span id="result" style="font-size:25px; color:red"> </span>
        <br>
        <br>
       
        <br><br><br>
       
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="cancella" style=" background- color:red; width:160px; height:50px" value="Ritenta" onclick="reset()">
       
       
    </form>
    </div>
    <br><br><br><br><br>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Fix what?  You need to tell us what the problem is!  Please use the javascript inline snippet to turn your post into a complete, minimal example that shows your error as well.

Comment: First step would be to fix the syntax errors which are listed in the console of the browser.

Comment: How to fix what?

Comment: Why do you have double quotes at the end of `document.getElementById()` in your `reset()` function... I suggest you open the browser console and check for errors... because even after fixing that you will notice another error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined** so this tells me no debugging has been done.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var howManyNumbers = 5;
var rememberNumbersArray = []; // We do not repeat numbers

createInput("userInputId", false, "Type number from 1 to 10");
createInput("inputId", true);

// create 6 (howManyNumbers) inputs
function createInput(name, disabled, placeholder){
 for(var e = 0; e<howManyNumbers; e++){
  lottery.innerHTML+=e+". ";
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.type = "text";
  input.id = name+e; // id 
  if(placeholder){
   input.placeholder = placeholder;
  }
  input.disabled = disabled;
  lottery.appendChild(input); // put it into the DOM
  lottery.innerHTML+="<BR><BR>"; // gap :D you can use &nbsp;
 }
}

function randomNumbers(){
 // clear rememberNumbersArray for next lottery :D
 rememberNumbersArray = [];
 
 // clear results
 results.innerHTML = "";
 
 var count = howManyNumbers;
 var numberRnd = 0;
 var rndNmb = 0;
 var count = 0;

 while(count<howManyNumbers){
  // ...random
  rndNmb = mt_rand(10,1);
  
  if(rememberNumbersArray.indexOf(rndNmb)==-1){
   // update input
   document.getElementById("inputId"+count).value = rndNmb;
   // Remember a random number
   rememberNumbersArray.push(rndNmb);
   // if count == howManyNumbers, break the loop
   count++; 
  }
 }
 
 // check if somebody win
 checkWin(count);
}

function checkWin(id){
 results.innerHTML = "Winning numbers: <BR>";
 for(var e = 0; e<rememberNumbersArray.length; e++){
  for(var a = 0; a<howManyNumbers; a++){
   if(rememberNumbersArray[e]==document.getElementById("userInputId"+a).value){
    results.innerHTML += rememberNumbersArray[e]+"<BR>";
   }
  }
 }

}

function mt_rand(max, min){
 return Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
}
```

```html
Welcome to ITALIA SUPER LOTTO 2017<BR><BR>
<div id="lottery"></div>
<button onclick="randomNumbers();">Generate</button>
<div id="results"></div>
```